# How can I provide an additional implementation of class methods with std::vector<TElement> as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a dictionary class based on RB-trees. My goal is to provide additional methods when the second element in data pair is std::vector.

I've tried writing it like

```cpp
template <typename TKey, typename TELement>
typename RBDictionary<TKey, std::vector<TElement>>::Node* RBDictionary<TKey, std::vector<TELement>>::Node::insertBST(Node*& root, Node*& ptr) {
//some code...
}
```

But it gives me compiler error: `Nested name specifier 'RBDictionary<TKey, std::vector<TELement> >::Node::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization`

Any ideas how can I make that?

Originally this method has the following signature

```cpp
template <typename TKey, typename TELement>
typename RBDictionary<TKey, TELement>::Node* RBDictionary<TKey, TELement>::Node::insertBST(Node*& root, Node*& ptr)
```

I expect to have different methods: one for any `TElement` type and one specifically for when `"TElement"` is a `std::vector<TElement>`

Comment: "_But it gives me compiler error._" What compiler error? Please provide the message, that it provides.

Comment: It looks like you want to provide a partial specialization of the whole class, not of individual member functions.

Comment: *it gives me compiler error*. And what is the error? We can't know it without having definition of RBDictionary.

Comment: There are several solutions to the problem. Which one would be best to use depends on what exactly you are trying to do. In any case you cannot (partially) specialize a member function based on the class template parameters without (partially) specializing the whole class.

Comment: @uneven_mark so initially my dictionary does not store different keys. I want to specify a case where inserted items with equal keys will be stored in a vector.

Comment: So basically you want to make the map a multi-map if the element type is specified to be `std::vector`? I don't think this is a good design choice at all, because it would result in not being able to store actual `std::vector` as elements in the map. You might want to use a type tag or completely different type (as the standard library does it) for this.

Comment: @uneven_mark so I'd better provide an explicit class for this case rather than specify an implementation in a general case?

Comment: @l.marder At the very least the user of the container should be able to specifically choose which of the two cases they want to use, retaining the possibility to use `std::vector` as element type in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a partial specialization of your class:

```
template <typename TKey, typename TELement>
class  RBDictionary {
    // Default class definition
};

template <typename TKey, typename TELement>
class RBDictionary<TKey, std::vector<TElement>> {
    // Specialized version
};
```

You need to define all members in both definitions, not only the once that are different and you also need to define all the methods for both cases (with the syntax you used in the question).

In order to reduce repetition you can define a base class from which both of these templates inherit and put all the common stuff in there.

There are other ways of doing this, especially if the differences between the two implementations of the class are small, but from your comment about the use case, I assume that the differences are going to be sufficiently large to make this approach reasonable.